# How can i access a property in a state's array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I have an array inside a state property in a react component.
How can I access this instance to change the render composition?

How want to access the "hasDiscount" feature with an arrow function
to enable the thumbnail. So the old price it's striked and the discount price it's featured. 
I want to, if the object has a discount price on load, the discount price has to show has the main price.

````
import Thumbnail from './thumbnail';

class Thumbnails extends Component {
        state = {
        thumbnails: [
        {id: 1, imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/200", href: "www.google.com", title: "title 1", category1: 'component', category2: 'tabs', price: 99, hasDiscount: 23},
        {id: 2, imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/200", href: "www.google.com", title: "title 2", category1: 'component', category2: 'tabs', price: 994, hasDiscount: 0},
        {id: 3, imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/200", href: "www.google.com", title: "title 3", category1: 'component', category2: 'tabs', price: 949, hasDiscount: 0},
        {id: 4, imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/200", href: "www.google.com", title: "title 4", category1: 'component', category2: 'tabs', price: 99, hasDiscount: 23},
        ]
};

hasDiscountTag = () => {

        ))
}

render() {


return (
<div className="thumbnails-container">   
        <h2 className="section-title">Components</h2>
        <div className="thumbnails-container-wrapper"> 
        {this.state.thumbnails.map(thumbnail => (
                <Thumbnail 
                        onLoad = {this.hasDiscountTag()}
                        key={thumbnail.id} 
                        name={thumbnail.title} 
                        id={thumbnail.id} 
                        price={thumbnail.price} 
                        imageUrl={thumbnail.imageUrl} 
                        href={thumbnail.href}
                        category1={thumbnail.category1}
                        category2={thumbnail.category2}
                        hasDiscount = {thumbnail.hasDiscount}
                        >
                </Thumbnail>
        ))} 
        </div>     
</div>
);

}
}

export default Thumbnails;```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach

```
 import Thumbnail from './thumbnail';

    class Thumbnails extends Component {
            state = {
            oldPrice: 0,
            thumbnails: [
            {id: 1, imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/200", href: "www.google.com", title: "title 1", category1: 'component', category2: 'tabs', price: 99, hasDiscount: 23},
            {id: 2, imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/200", href: "www.google.com", title: "title 2", category1: 'component', category2: 'tabs', price: 994, hasDiscount: 0},
            {id: 3, imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/200", href: "www.google.com", title: "title 3", category1: 'component', category2: 'tabs', price: 949, hasDiscount: 0},
            {id: 4, imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/200", href: "www.google.com", title: "title 4", category1: 'component', category2: 'tabs', price: 99, hasDiscount: 23},
            ]
    };

    hasDiscountTag = (price, hasDiscount) => {
         this.setState({oldPrice: price-hasDiscount})
            ))
    }

    render() {


    return (
    <div className="thumbnails-container">   
            <h2 className="section-title">Components</h2>
            <h2 className="section-title">Price: {this.state.oldPrice}</h2>
            <div className="thumbnails-container-wrapper"> 
            {this.state.thumbnails.map(thumbnail => (
                    <Thumbnail 
                            onLoad = {this.hasDiscountTag}
                            key={thumbnail.id} 
                            name={thumbnail.title} 
                            id={thumbnail.id} 
                            price={thumbnail.price} 
                            imageUrl={thumbnail.imageUrl} 
                            href={thumbnail.href}
                            category1={thumbnail.category1}
                            category2={thumbnail.category2}
                            hasDiscount = {thumbnail.hasDiscount}
                            >
                    </Thumbnail>
            ))} 
            </div>     
    </div>
    );

    }
    }

    export default Thumbnails;
```